# Nest Maps to display with For Each on HTML

Tags: lightning-web-components, html

I am having trouble displaying my data in an efficient way in my HTML
I am importing data in my JS through the wire attribute that look the following way
[image]

When I console.log the Data I can see it perfectly
Now I would like to render it in my HTML
And I would like for each item to print the key and the data associated to it.
so for example

```
United State:
IcData, 0 item
ICApprovedData, 2 item 
ect ect
```

my JS look the following way:

```
import { LightningElement,wire, api } from 'lwc';
import getApprovalKeyFigures from '@salesforce/apex/ApprovalDashboard.ApprovalKPI';

export default class ApprovalKeyFigures extends LightningElement {
    kpiData;
    @wire(getApprovalKeyFigures)
    retrieveApprovalKpi({error, data}){
        if(data){ 
            this.kpiData = data
            this.IcEurope = data.Europe;
            
            console.log(this.kpiData)
            console.log(this.IcEurope)

            }
        }
}
```

I tried to fora:each kpiData.data but nothiung seems to work

Could you give me a hand ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over Maps, only Arrays. So, your first task would be to convert the Map as an Array:

```
this.kpiData = Object.keys(data).map(key => ({ name: key, ...data[key] }));
```

You can then use `for:each={kpiData}` to render this data. Feel free to change the `name` to whatever you feel would make the most sense for your data.

Comment: Thx you ! Could you explain me the line ? 
the ...data[key] ?

Comment: @Ben2pop This is the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), you use it to copy an object's properties, a list of array elements, or for rest parameters (here, we use it to copy an object).

Comment: Thx you I ll dig into that, thx for your help ;)